# Save specific objects for each device in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to migrate an app I had built which used **Parse** as its cloud backend. In my Parse backend database, I had a table which stored data as shown below:

```
Device ID | Contacts  
xxxxx001   | "(800)-888-8888"  
xxxxx002   | "(800)-888-8858"  
xxxxx003   | "(800)-888-8868"
```

Over here, device ID is the android device ID and the Contacts are an ArrayList of strings which was generated through logic on the device. Basically, the user would select a contact (multiple in future iterations, hence it being an ArrayList, for testing I'm just keeping one item in the list) and that contact is saved for that DeviceID in the backend database. If the same DeviceID changes the contact, the contacts ArrayList in the database corresponding to its DeviceID would be *replaced* with the new ArrayList.

I'm trying to get something similar set up on Firebase, however right now it seems I only have a global variable on my databse which seems to get updated each time I press my button.

**Here is my code for the button:**

```
DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference  mContactsRef = mRootRef.child("contacts");

@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mButtonContactSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mContactsRef.setValue(contacts); //contacts is an arraylist with 1 item
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is how it looks in Firebase after clicking the button 3 times:

[image]

Instead of updating the value, `it seems to add another row(?) of to store the current phone number selected`. How can I go about setting up a DeviceID->(Objects to be stored per device)
sort of setup?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `push()`, which generates a unique ID for new items.

From the [Firebase documentation on reading and writing lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#reading_and_writing_lists):

```
// Create a new post reference with an auto-generated id
var newPostRef = postListRef.push();
newPostRef.set({
    // ...
});
```

The new items will have complex-looking keys of the form `-KTTHEScy82fpfNSCoYN`. Read this [article on why those are preferred over array indices](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) and (if you're interested) this [article that explains the format of these keys](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html).

### Consider a different data model

In general though you might want to consider a different data model. What you're storing is a collection of phone numbers. At first sight, storing those in an array-like list seems fine.

But typically you'll want these behaviors for this contact list:

- each phone number can only be present once
- you need to find whether a given phone number is already in the list

With your current structure you can only see if a number is already in the list by scanning all items in the list. Whenever that is the case, it is a good moment to consider using a set data structure instead.

In Firebase you'd model a set of phone numbers like this:

```
"contacts": {
    "(800)-888-8858": true
    "(800)-888-8868": true
    "(800)-888-8888": true
}
```

While this structure initially looks less efficient, it is actually stored more efficiently than the array list in Firebase. And looking up whether an item exists is now a simple existence check instead of having to scan the array. And with this structure it is impossible to store the same number twice.

Comment: Thank you for the response! So on my client side app, how would I go about modifying my data structure to fit the model that Firebase prefers? Or do you mean I should store it in a HashSet?
Also, how would I go about using the push() method to make sure I'm storing things to device ID? As someone used to relational databases, I'm having a bit of trouble with the JSON storage system that Firebase uses and the lack of proper tables.